# How can we find the bounds of the following integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration

How can we find the bounds of the following integrals?
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\phi(x,y)dxdy$$ where  $\phi(x,y)=$ $\begin{cases} 1  \quad if \quad x=y>0 \\ 0 \quad otherwise \end{cases}$ or $\phi(x,y)=$ $\begin{cases} 1  \quad if \quad x+y>z \\ 0 \quad otherwise \end{cases}$

I'm really confused with the first problem when it is just a line in the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, if $y$ is fixed then there is only one possible value of $x$. Therefore the integral reduces to
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_y^y\;dxdy=\int_{0}^{\infty}0\;dy=0 $$
This makes sense because the integral is computing the area of the line $y=x$ in the first quadrant, which is $0$.

In the second case, the integral is computing the area of the intersection of the half-plane $x+y>z$ with the first quadrant. This area is infinite, so the integral is infinite. It might be helpful to draw a picture.

Comment: yes, I have drawn the picture and every thing appears to be clearer. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Where did you encounter these integrals?

**Case 1:**  The support of $\phi(x,y) = \mathbf 1_{x=y, y>0}$ is a ray.    The integral over the $[0;\infty)^2$ quadrant, has measure zero.

$$\iint_{x>0, y>0, x=y}\operatorname d (x,y) ~=~ \int_0^\infty \int_y^y \operatorname d x\operatorname d y ~=~0$$

**Case 2:** The support of $\phi(x,y) = \mathbf 1_{x+y>z}$ is a semi-infinite plane covering the far side of the line $y=z-x$ from the origin.   The integral over the $[0;\infty)^2$ quadrant is immense.

$$\iint_{x>0, y>0, x + y > z}\operatorname d (x,y) ~=~ \int_0^\infty\int_{\max(0,z-y)}^\infty \operatorname d x\operatorname d y ~=~ \infty$$

Are ewe shore that ewe half coffeed it whiteout arrows?

$$\iint_{x>0, y>0, x + y \leq z}\operatorname d (x,y) ~=~ \int_0^{\max(z,0)}\int_{0}^{\max(z-y,0)} \operatorname d x\operatorname d y ~=~ \max(\dfrac{z^2}{2}, 0) $$

Comment: this problem is in probability. I found easier if drawing a picture. Anw, your illustration makes sense to me !